# Does comparators in priority Queue works in reverse than normal comparators in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, comparator, priority-queue

I tried making the same comparator for vector and priority queue, but they give reverse results. Why is it so?

Code:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return a<b;
    }
};

bool compare(int a, int b)
{
    return a<b;
}
int main()
{
  priority_queue<int,vector<int>, cmp> numbers;

  vector<int>v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(20);
  v.push_back(7);
  sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);

  numbers.push(1);
  numbers.push(20);
  numbers.push(7);

  cout << "Priority Queue: ";

  while(!numbers.empty()) {
    cout << numbers.top() << ", ";   
    numbers.pop();
  }

  cout << endl;

 cout<<"Vector: "; 
 int i=0;
while(i<v.size()) {
    cout << v[i] << ", ";   
    i++;
  }

  cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

//Output:
Priority Queue: 20, 7, 1, 
Vector: 1, 7, 20,
```

//Output:
Priority Queue: 20, 7, 1,
Vector: 1, 7, 20,

Please clarify the confusion. Thanks

Comment: Try not to think of it as "reverse" vs. not. Think of it as what it is: a *comparator of priority level*. You're comparing *priority* level of two items against each other. The purpose of the comparator is to relay whether the first argument sports a priority that is strictly *less* than the second argument. So do that. The container adapter will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: If you would use a sorted vector in place of the priority queue you would use the back of the vector as front of the queue because that way is more efficient. So Using a vector you would get 20, 7, 1 as order too. But really it's arbitrary if you consider the lowest or highest value as having the most priority.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they work in reverse. For one possible reference, see cppreference's [description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) of `std::priority_queue`:

> **Template parameters**
>
> [...]
>
> `Compare` -   A [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) type providing a strict weak ordering.
>
> Note that the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) parameter is defined such that it returns `true` if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to the weak ordering imposed by [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: ya, this is very interesting, is there anyone can explain why? why does it designed in reverse way